# Get bits from an array of uint's in C++

Tags: c++, bit

Let's say I have an array of `uint32_t`, N elements.
The content of the array is only meaningful if I unpack the entire `N*32` bits into small fragments.

The fragment size can be highly irregular: 1 segment of 5 bits, 2 segment of 7 bits, 1 segment of 48 bits, ... Any pattern is possible.

What is the fastest way to unpack the array?

I was thinking of using a large `std::bitset<N*32>`, convert to a string and the read the sub-strings; but it's kind of slow.
As another possibility, for each fragment, I was thinking to:

- locate the index in the array of the starting "pointer"
- locate the index in the array of the end "pointer"
- locate, in the single located array element, where the starting/ending bit
- do a loop and read bit by bit and merge

Working but I bet there must be something more simple.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I had a project once that needed something like this.  I wrote a wrapper class that held the array, and maintained the current element index and bit index within that element.  Then I simply looped through the array, masking and shifting individual bits as needed, incrementing the indexes as I went along.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812572/is-bitset-faster-than-an-array-of-bools

Comment: What you want is basically a bitstream parser. There are a few open source implementations.
You can also get some inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293157/reading-n-bit-elements-from-a-data-stream-in-c
Converting to a string is definitely slower than shifting and masking.

Comment: Indeed it seems bitstream parsers are a very common need and I am kind of surprised that there's nos standard access (like a std slice operator of function or similar). The last url has a very nice and compact idea.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the the fastest way to unpack the array?

Bitwise operations.

Comment: Easy and fast, indeed!